# pointers with OpenMP

Tags: c++, c++11, openmp

i am trying to use OpenMP in my program (i am newbie using OpenMP) and the program return in two places errors.

Here is an example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <omp.h>

class CNachbarn {
public:
    CNachbarn () { a = 0; }
    uint32_t Get_Next_Neighbor() { return a++; }

private:
    uint32_t a;
};

class CNetwork {
public:
    CNetwork ( uint32_t num_elements_ );
    ~CNetwork();
    void Validity();
    void Clean();

private:
    uint32_t num_elements;
    uint32_t nachbar;

    std::vector<uint32_t> remove_node_v;
    CNachbarn *Nachbar;
};

CNetwork::CNetwork( uint32_t num_elements_  ) {
    num_elements = num_elements_;
    Nachbar = new CNachbarn();

    remove_node_v.reserve( num_elements );
}

CNetwork::~CNetwork() {
    delete Nachbar;
}

inline void CNetwork::Validity() {
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for ( uint32_t i = 0 ; i < num_elements ; i++ ) {
        #pragma omp critical
        remove_node_v.push_back(i);
    }
}

void CNetwork::Clean () {
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for ( uint8_t j = 0 ; j < 2 ; j++ ) {
        nachbar = Nachbar->Get_Next_Neighbor();
        std::cout << "i: " << i << ", neighbor: " << nachbar << std::endl;
    }

    remove_node_v.clear();
}

int main() {
    uint32_t num_elements = 1u << 3;
    uint32_t i            = 0;
    CNetwork Network( num_elements );

    do {
        Network.Validity();
        Network.Clean();
    } while (++i < 2);

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to know

1. if #pragma omp critical is a good solution for `push_back()`? (Does solve this problem?) would it be better to define for each thread its own vector and then combine them (using insert() )? or some kind of `lock`?
2. In my original code i get a running error at: `nachbar = Nachbar->Get_Next_Neighbor( &remove_node_v[i] );` but in this example not. Nether the less,  i would like OpenMP to use as the number of cores `CNachbarn` classes, since `CNachbarn` is recursive computation and should not be influenced from the other threads. The question is how to do it smarty? (I dont think it is smart to define `CNachbarn` each time i start the for-loop, since i call this function more the million times in my simulation and time is important.

Comment: Please post a *minimal example* that illustrates your problem. You’re loading off all the work to us here.

Comment: 1. Do you really need a vector here? Looks like you can eliminate critical section using simple array, if it is possible to introduce some kind of "invalid" value to memset that array with. You can then scan this array and push all non-invalid values to a vector. Depending on task size, it can give you a significant boost or no boost at all, but I believe you won't be using OMP for non-time-consuming loop.

Comment: @Konrad, i uploaded a working example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning your first problem:
Your function Validity is a perfect way to achieve below serial performance in a parallel loop. However, you already gave the correct answer. You should fill independent vectors for each thread and merge them afterwards.

```
inline void CNetwork::Validity() {
#pragma omp parallel for 
for ( uint32_t i = 0 ; i < num_elements ; i++ ) {
    #pragma omp critical
    remove_node_v.push_back(i);
}
}
```

**EDIT:** A possible remedy could look like this (if you require serial access to your elements, you need to change the loop a bit)

```
inline void CNetwork::Validity() {
remove_node_v.reserve(num_elements);
#pragma omp parallel 
{
  std::vector<uint32_t> remove_node_v_thread_local;
  uint32_t thread_id=omp_get_thread_num();
  uint32_t n_threads=omp_get_num_threads();
  for ( uint32_t i = thread_id ; i < num_elements ; i+=n_threads ) 
    remove_node_v_thread_local.push_back(i);

  #pragma omp critical
  remove_node_v.insert(remove_node_v.end(), remove_node_v_thread_local.begin(), remove_node_v_thread_local.end()); 
}
}
```

Your second problem could be solved by defining an array of CNachbarn with the size of the maximum number of OMP threads possible, and access distinct elements of the array from each thread like:

```
CNachbarn* meine_nachbarn=alle_meine_nachbarn[omp_get_thread_num()]
```

Comment: i would like to use local std::vector with push_back in each thread and then to combine the all the local std::vectors into remove_node_v std::vector. How could i do it?